# Каким способом лучше создать игровое поле?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста каким способом лучше создать **игровое поле**, по которому в дальнейшем будет ходить созданный мною **объект**? (в среде разработки *delphi*)
Требуется для курсовой)
Я читал про способ с текстовым файлом, заполняется нулями, где нужны некие объекты ставят единичку, фигуры: 2, но я не особо сильно визуально себе это представляю, так же читал что можно реализовать как то с помощью компонентов *TImage* или *TPaintbox*
Заранее спасибо за ответы..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброго времени суток и Вам! Я так понимаю вы ориентированы на 2D-графику, а не 3D. Вы слышали когда-нибудь о канве в Delphi, о технологии GDI и GDI+? Если нет, то вам надо начать отталкиваться от этого и изучать сначала это. Вообще если игровое поле надо создать, то действительно можно через файл или БД (хуже если в массиве) хранить поле для рисования, а на нем размещать какие-либо объекты. Желательно использовать ООП программирования. Насчет компонентов, верно лучше использовать либо TImage, либо TPaintbox. Хотя канва рисуется даже на голой форме... Вот примеры моих работ (в виде скришотов) в которых активно применяется графика:

Простая игрушка с игровым полем:

[image]

Программа для работы с изображениями (вращение, масштабирование, растягивание):
[image]

Геоинформационная система на делфи.
[image]

Все проекты мои, если заинтересовало что-то могу поделиться знаниями и исходниками. Обращайтесь, мне не жалко)).

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ)

Comment: Если надо, могу исходники прислать). Говори ящик свой).

Comment: можно исходник 1 программы с игровым полем? i-xe@mail.ru Заранее большое спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Для двумерных лучше всего, на мой взгляд — `TCanvas`. С помощью него можно спокойно рисовать примитивы (квадраты, круги, линии), а также уже готовые картинки.

Вот и мои примеры на канве:

[image: арканоид]

Надо понимать процесс рисования. Например, сначала рисуем картинку за кадром. Как нарисовали — выводим уже готовую картинку вперед, и начинаем рисовать новый кадр.

Если нужна 3D-графика, то на мой вкус — OpenGL:

[image: OpenGL_example]